# onDestory () in service in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I would like to to restart my service whenever it is stopped by Android or task killers?

For which I am trying **start_Sticky** using the below code in onStartCommand():

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

This works fine for Android versions below 4.4.2. Hence, I thought I can restart the service whenever the OnDestroy() is called in the service?

Is this possible or is there any other workaround for 4.4.2 version?

When is OnDestroy in Service is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set an `alarmanager` to call the `service` after particular interval of time regularly.If service is all ready running then no need to start once again else start the service.

Comment: Wont the alarm manager part be killed too through taskKiller?

Comment: never it is taken care by OS itself... but u need to re-register ur alarm after boot also. bcoz after boot alarm dosenot works

Comment: Oh ok. In that case I will just have it run in the mainActivity and bootReceiver..

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy will be called when you kill the Service.However, it will not be called,when you kill the progress.

Keeping service alive is a big problem.

Comment: START_STICKY seems to be working just fine but not on 4.4.2 I would like to solve that part?

Comment: this should be comment not answer

Comment: I just answer his/her question "When is OnDestroy in Service is called?"

Comment: sorry buddy..keep going

Comment: Thanks @zhenghuiyan. I thought I can start the service onDestroy. I guess it will not work.